# What are Parva days and restrictions on cutting trees

Tags: brahma, indra

When [Brahma was distributing](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12b109.htm) Indra's sin of killing Brahmin, he asks trees to take portion. The trees asks for the means how they can be rescued from this. Then,

> Brahman said, 'This sin that you shall take shall possess the man who through stupefaction of judgment will cut or tear any of you when Parva days come.'

Question is what are *parva* days? Does any other Smriti or text describe similar restrictions on cutting plants?

Answer (score 3):

Parva days are mentioned in Manu Smriti on multiple occasions. Here is one such instance:

> 4.150. Let him always offer on the Parva-days oblations to Savitri and such as avert evil omens, and on the Ashtakas and Anvashtakas let him
> constantly worship the manes.

A different translation of the above verse and commentary on it can be found from [here](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc200258.html):

> सावित्रान् शान्तिहोमांश्च कुर्यात् पर्वसु नित्यशः ।
> पितॄंश्चैवाष्टकास्वर्चेन्नित्यमन्वष्टकासु च ॥ १५० ॥
>
> sāvitrān śāntihomāṃśca kuryāt **parvasu** nityaśaḥ |
> pitṝṃścaivāṣṭakāsvarcennityamanvaṣṭakāsu ca || 150 ||
>
> **On special days**, he shall always offer the oblations to Savitṛ, and
> also the Pacificatory Oblations; on the “Aṣtakas” and on the
> “Anvaṣṭakas” he shall always worship the Pitṛs.’—(150)

Medhatithi's commentary on this verse explains that Amavasya and Purnima are considered as the Parva days.

> The exact forms of the afore-mentioned oblations are now described.
>
> ‘Oblations to Savitṛ.’—Those that are offered to Savitṛ as the deity.
>
> **‘Special days;’—i.e., on the Moonless and the Full Moon Days**—the said oblations are to be offered.
>
> ‘Pacificatory oblations—the oblations that are offered for the purpose
> of averting evil.

Comment: Parva literal meaning comes as special or festive. Wanted to see if there is any definition for this.

Comment: Even in our mother tongue Parva refers to any festival/auspicious days and not just the Purnima and Amavasya Tithis as Medhatithi has said. Need to see what other sources have to say. @Kanthri